# case statement for 2 different rows

Tags: sql, case

I am having trouble returning a value with 2 different rows

```
acct # | Loan 1  |Parent Loan|Variable
-------|-------- |-----------|-----------
1      | 1       |1          |Fixed
1      | 2       |1          |Variable
2      | 1       |1          |Fixed
3      | 1       |1          |Variable
4      | 1       |1          |Variable
```

The expexted result would be

account 1 parent loan 1 = mixed

account 2 would be fixed

account 3 and 4 would be variable

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you actually want to achieve. Please be more clear.

Comment: A good place to start. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am trying to bucket the parent by Fixed Variable or mixed

Comment: What defines 'mixed'?  That it has two rows?  

Also, what does the 'Loan 1' column represent?

Comment: Mixed would be a fixed and a variable under the same parent.
a loan can have option to draw a fixed portion and a variable portion

Comment: so in the example above acct 1 has 2 loans with the same parent one option is fixed the other is variable which would be the mixed option

Comment: Is it possible for Account 1 to have 2 Fixed Loans under the same parent?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: So, if an account had 2 'Fixed' loans under the same parent, then the 'Variable' column would have a value of 'Fixed'?

Comment: Yes that is correct it would only be mixed if it had a fixed and a variable. it can have 4 or 5 loans under the parent that could vary by fixed or variable

Answer (score 0):

This *might* be the answer you're looking for given the additional information that your provided in the comments above.  If not, then I am hoping it is close.

You need to count the number of DISTINCT Loan Types ('Variable' or 'Fixed') and then join that back to the original table.  Effectively a subquery for each AccountId:

```
select 
  child.AccountId,
  child.LoanId,
  child.ParentId,
  rollup.ModifiedLoanType
from Accounts child
join (select 
        AccountId, 
        case (count(distinct LoanType)) when 1 then LoanType else 'Mixed' end as ModifiedLoanType from Accounts group by AccountId) rollup
  on rollup.AccountId = child.AccountId
group by child.AccountId
order by child.AccountId, child.LoanId
```

See it in action as a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdfea/5).  If it isn't exactly what you need, then you can tinker with it, and/or I can help you revise it